# Trying to import a .csv file in pandas using python. Getting Unicode Decode error

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import a .csv file into pandas but I am getting a Unicode error. I am running a windows pc.

I am using the following command:

```
medals =pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\\data\\olympicmedals.csv')
```

What am I missing here?

This is just to import a .csv file into my notebook

I am using the following command:

```
medals =pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\\data\\olympicmedals.csv')
```

The file should be imported into my Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
medals =pd.read_csv(r"C:\\Users\\Username\\Downloads\\data\\olympicmedals.csv")
```